# How to find my ID in Skype for Business?

Tags: skype-for-business

I would like to invite someone external to my organization to be part of a Skype for Business meeting which I am setting up in Outlook. I sent him a connection request using the Skype ID he gave me, but it doesn't seem to be working, so he asked me for my Skype ID so we can connect that way. Where can I find out what my ID is in Skype for Business?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be your username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Skype for Business, your Sign In Address functions as an ID.

However, knowing that probably won't help, since it sounds like you have a different issue.
By default, Skype for Business networks cannot communicate with regular Skype (personal) accounts.

[This article from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/set-up-skype-for-business-online/let-skype-for-business-users-add-skype-contacts) describes how to enable communication between your Skype for Business and regular Skype accounts.

However, it's a bit more complicated.  At least according to [this other article from Microsoft,](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-for-people-in-skype-for-business-b12500ef-e37f-4d22-aade-c11277e53f19?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) it's still not possible for Skype users to search for Skype for Business users *at all*.

> "While you can search for and find Skype users, they can not search for
>   and find Skype for Business users."

If that seems surprising and frustrating, bear in mind that Skype and Skype for Business are actually two different services.  They have very little to do with each other, and are not particularly integrated.

Comment: Thanks. For my company, my sign in ID is my work email address, so this is my Skype for Business ID. As far as I can tell, you can't find this on the Skype for Business window; you just have to know. You are right about Skype and Skype for Business not being integrated. I sent a contact request from Skype for Business to the outside person using the Skype ID he gave me, and he did't get it.

Answer (score 1):

our Skype ID is a unique name associated with your account, which can't be changed.
To find what your Skype ID is, you just need to open your Skype profile. You can do this both on your desktop, and in the mobile app for iPhone and Android.
You used to be able to set your own Skype ID, but it's now created and given to you when you make your Skype account.